# To Use Shape.DrawSpline Method (Visio) from MS Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, visio

I was reading up on the use of Shape.DrawSpline Method (Visio) from MS office VBA reference.  The example they gave works when I entered it within Visio.  The example takes points and connect them with a curve and display it in the Visio application.

I wish to have the VBA code reside within MS Access and I will have VBA code open a Visio drawing, and execute the Shape.DrawSpline Method from MS Access VBA code.  My problem seems to determine how to generate the expression shape to get the program to run and draw the sample curve in the open Visio drawing.

Here is the code I was working on, and the part that opens up a Visio drawing is working for me:

```
Dim AppVisio As Visio.Application
Dim ShpObj As Visio.Shape
Dim XYPoints(70) As Double

Set AppVisio = CreateObject("Visio.Application")
Set DocObj = AppVisio.Documents.Open("C:\Test Template.vsd")
```

When I command MS Access to execute the above code, the Visio Drawing "Test Template.vsd" does open it.

Immediately following the above code, I have the x, y coordinates of the points to be ploted.  They are assigned to the XYPoints array.

At the bottom, I have the following code which was used to execute the DrawSpline Method (Visio) from MS Access VBA code.

Here is that code:

```
Set ShpObj = AppVisio.Application.ActivePage.DrawSpline(XYPoints, 0.25, visSplinePeriodic)
```

I get an error in the above statement.  Here is the error I get:
    "Run-time error '-2032465751 (86db08a9)'
    Method 'DrawSpline' of object 'IVPage' failed

Thank You,

Comment: Some thoughts: Try to make it work in Visio VBA first. are the XYPoints correct?

Comment: Yes, I have done that already.  I first tried using the same code in the Visio drawing and it does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agrree with @y4cine's advice.  However my guess is either your document isn't opening correctly, or your populating of your points array isn't in the correct format.  The following adaptation of [the SDK sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/visio-vba/articles/page-drawspline-method-visio) works for me:

```
Sub TestSplineFromExcel()

Dim vApp As Visio.Application
Set vApp = CreateObject("Visio.Application")

Dim intCounter As Integer
Dim XYPoints(1 To (5 * 2)) As Double

For intCounter = 1 To 5
    'Set x components (array elements 1,3,5,7,9) to 1,2,3,4,5
    XYPoints((intCounter * 2) - 1) = intCounter

    'Set y components (array elements 2,4,6,8,10) to f(i)
    XYPoints(intCounter * 2) = (intCounter * intCounter) - (7 * intCounter) + 15
Next intCounter

vApp.Documents.Add ""

Dim vPag As Visio.Page
Set vPag = vApp.ActivePage

If vPag Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Target page is null"
Else
    Dim shp As Visio.Shape
    Set shp = vPag.DrawSpline(XYPoints, 0.25, Visio.VisDrawSplineFlags.visSplinePeriodic)
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What is your vApp.Documents.Add "" statement doing?   I don't understand that.   It looks like you are using excel VBA in the above to generate the XYPoints.   Is the vApp.Documents.Add "" used to open a Visio document here??   That is almost what I am trying to do.  My statement for opening Visio is correct because I tested it by point a curve on the blank Visio form except for the scaling of the form.   I was able to write VBA Code and change the color and weight of the lines from MS Access VBA.  I tested my points with VBA embedded in Visio.  Suggestions?

Comment: Do you think it may be of help if I post a link to download my example?

Comment: I got it to work, my data.  I basically use your template and put in my data and made some minor changes.  The most important part was Set shp = vPag.DrawSpline(XYPoints, 0.25, Visio.VisDrawSplineFlags.visSplinePeriodic).   Thanks Again....  Its working for me.

Comment: Glad to hear you're fixed.  If you could mark as answered (if you feel it is) that would be helpful.